# using http basic auth to login to mutiple virtual hosts at once under apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost, basic-authentication

I have 2 virtual hosts under one domain: a.mydomain.com, b.mydomain.com.
And in the global configuration of apache I have the following:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/password_http_auth
Require user mydomain_user
</Directory>
```

This works well for all the virtual hosts to have basic auth protection. However, I need to enter username and password for a.mydomain.com and b.mydomain after I went to mydomain.com and authenticate there.

So my question is: is there a way to do authentication on mydomain.com only and that user do not need to enter username and password again for all the virtual hosts under this domain?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

Any configuration done in the httpd.conf or apache2.conf is a global configuration and will apply to all of your configured sites.

To only have it apply to one of the sites. Move the auth configurations to the specific virtual host configuration file

```
<Directory />
  # keep these
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None

  # move these to the vhost configuration you want to protect
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Area"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/password_http_auth
  Require user mydomain_user
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for someone:

I have a single virtual host with many aliases. It is a multisite set up with a single source code for multiple websites. I needed a basic authentication for some of the hosts but not for others while the virtual host is common for all the hosts/domains.

Here is ow I did it and it works fine (Apache 2.4 / Ubuntu 18LTS):

```
SetEnvIf Host "secure\.host\.com" SECURED
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/secure-dir/" SECURED
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Basic Auth Message"
AuthUserFile /var/www/public-html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
```

In the above example I also have a secured directory (line 2) which works with regular expression so it will match with any file in that directory.

On line 1 is the secured host name. Please note the backslash before each dot character!

Add as many lines for hosts or directories as you need.